# How to set img size to not overflow?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a div with a fixed height, which contains a span with some text and a img element. How can I set the img height to be equal to the div height minus the span height ?

Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div { height: 100px; width: 800px; border-style:solid;}
img { display: block}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>

<span>hello world</span>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: note: The height/width are fixed values, but are unknown variables.

Comment: Can you try javascript?

Comment: I guess... but is it the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can add this to the `div`:

```
  display: flex; // set a flexbox container
  flex-direction: column; // column placement
  align-items: flex-start; // prevent default stretching in cross-axis (horizontal)
```

and add `max-height: 100%` and `min-height: 0` to the image (add `min-height: 0` to the `span` too) - see demo below:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100px;
  width: 800px;
  border-style: solid;
}

img {
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}
span {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i've personally tried it. Why the height goes down a little it's because of the

`<p>Hello World</p>` so it will create a space

The code :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div { height: 100px; width: 800px; border-style:solid;}
img { display: block;width:100%;height:100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>

<span>hello world</span>
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @KevinFox, i've editted the answer and the explanation

Answer (score 0):

add this in your css, put 100% in your img to fit the height of your div.

```
img{ 
display: block;
height: 100%;
}
```

this is for your text but if you want to fit the image in your div you can use absolute in your text.

```
span{
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: In this case, the span and img overlap, don't they?

Comment: yes.. can you give me a screenshot the exact output you want.. send me a sample and i will help you.. the question is slightly confusing to me..

Comment: Basically I want both the text and the img to be in the same div, but without overlapping or without overflowing...

Answer (score 0):

try to use [**CSS3 box-sizing property**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) like this.

```
div {
  height: 100px; 
  width: 800px; 
  border-style:solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

on you html:

```
<div>

   <span>Lorem Ipsum is including versions of Lorem Ipsum</span>
   <div>
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does not seem to work either, the img is still outside the border

Answer (score 0):

I have did this with css `calc` property take a look on this snippet

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```css
div {
   height: 100px;
   width: 800px;
   border-style: solid;
   float: left;
}
img {
   display: block;
   max-height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div> 
 <span>hello world</span> 
 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"/> 
</div>
```